# change in gfortran compiler leading to change of value

Tags: gfortran

I have a fortran program that was running compiled by gfortran4. On a new in a machine I had it recompiled with gfortran9. I noticed the results were different. After investigation it is so that at some point some array are very close between both versions but not exactly the same (a change of around 10^-9) and it ends change.
Is there a reason the change of compiler affect the code to a 10^-9? Is this the sign of something miscoded? (everything is supposed to be doble precision!)

Thanks.

Comment: We need much more information. Your compiler flags, optimizations you use, parallelization you use... 10^-9 can easily be the double precision rounding errors. A definitive answer is impossible  without a [mcve], one can only widely speculate.

Comment: the code is very huge, I haven't determine yet where it starts to diverge. There are no parrallelization and the compilation options are just -O2. The only thing clear is the 10^-9 differences become big after a call to a lapack routine (zggev)

Comment: If your matrices are near singular, matrix oprations can easily amplify small differences. Again, more details would be necessary.